# How to call SQL Server stored procedure from Cakephp

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, stored-procedures, procedure

I develop something where I must connect to a SQL Server database and call a stored procedure from that. I am looking for some solution because i tried a lot of different ways but i didn't succeed. For example the simplest:

```
$this->query('some working query');
```

I tried another way with a predefined behaviour I found at:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/icc97/2011/09/25/sql_server_storedprocedure_behaviour

but it failed too. Can someone explain me how I can do that?

Best for you all!
Zsolti

Comment: can you post your query here and also tell us what you are trying to achieve. We can't tell you what exactly to do if you are posting broad questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$this->modelName->query("Exec spName ");
```